# Why is MapRoute messing up?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, controller, actionlink

Keep in mind I am new to asp.net mvc, so I am aware that maybe my problem is really easy to solve. :)

I started a new ASP.NET project based on the MVC pattern si O got the whole HomeController and working website. So I added a new Controller (**CoursesController**) and a new route. But it's not working.

To show some of the work.

**CoursesController.cs** - Part of it

```
public class CoursesController : Controller
{
    private readonly CourseStore _store = new CourseStore();

    //
    // GET: /Course/
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(_store.GetCourses());
    }
```

**RouteConfig.cs**

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Courses",
            url: "Courses/{action}/{courseid}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Courses", action = "Index", courseid = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

_**Layout.cshtml** - Relevant link section

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Courses", "Index", "Courses")</li>
</ul>
```

**Result**
If I click the link in _layout I am sent to the url `http://localhost/Courses/` and I get a reply **You do not have permission to view this directory or page.**. 
But if I change the url manually to `http://localhost/Courses/Index` everything works fine.

Keep in mind the ActionLink only generates `http://localhost/Courses/`

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: put a breakpoint on return View(_store.GetCourses());, start debug and browse http://localhost/Courses/. Does it stop in the Index action?

Comment: I believe you have a folder "courses" under your site root directory, which will cause the url doesn't hit mvc routing at all. An quick way to solve this is to add `routes.RouteExistingFiles = true;`, but that's not suggested and may cause [other issues](http://forums.asp.net/t/1263849.aspx). Do you want/allowed to change the "Courses" folder name to something else that get around the routing?

Comment: WeTTTT, this is true, and is exactly what caused the problem. And of course it makes sense, I had a folder to keep some files regarding courses. Renamed the folder and now it works fine.

If you can please answer to this question I will mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is pasted from user WeTTTT as was the correct answer.

I believe you have a folder "courses" under your site root directory, which will cause the url doesn't hit mvc routing at all. An quick way to solve this is to add routes.RouteExistingFiles = true;, but that's not suggested and may cause other issues. Do you want/allowed to change the "Courses" folder name to something else that get around the routing? –  WeTTTT Mar 21 at 12:11